# Microsoft Excel Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I tried to use a previous formula to help me create another one but, I was unsuccessful. Can someone please assist me again with creating a formula that will say the following?

If cell f2 says "Core State Inc. - USA Semi-Monthly 1" then I want 000 to be entered into the cell
If cell f2 says "Core States Construction Services - USA Semi-Monthly 2" then I want 001 to be entered into the cell
If cell f2 says "Integrated Images" then I want 002 to be entered into the cell

Comment: look into a couple of functions.  if you only have a couple of choices you can build nested IF functions.  If you 4+ choices you may want to go another route and that is build a list in 1 column with the results in the adjacent column.  Then turn around  and use `VLOOKUP`, `LOOKUP`, or the ever popular `INDEX` and `MATCH` combination.

Comment: Use logical IF formula,, it's simple ☺

Comment: Could you provide a sample?

Answer (score 0):

use :

`=If(f2="Core State Inc. - USA Semi-Monthly 1","000",if(f2="Core States Construction Services - USA Semi-Monthly 2","001",if(f2="Integrated Images","002","")))`